# A particle moves along the $x$-axis according to the equation $x=10t-2t^2$ ... (Question about the wording)

Tags: calculus, physics

A particle moves along the $x$-axis according to the equation $x=10t-2t^2$. What is the total distance covered by the particle between $t=0$ and $t=3$?

I'm just not sure whether the question is asking to find the length of the arc or the integral of the absolute value of the function.

I just need help determining what the question is exactly asking... I already know how to complete the process, I just need to know which method to use. I thought that the particle was moving along the curve of the equation, but it asked for total distance, which makes me think of integrals.

Comment: `I thought that the particle was moving along the curve of the equation` But you wrote before that the `particle moves along the x-axis`.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, but then it says "according to the equation"... what does that exactly mean? I thought it meant that as the particle moves along the x axis, it follows the curvature of the equation

Comment: @Jee The equation gives you the position of the particle on the $x$ axis at any given time $t$.

Comment: First of all, this is a curve in $x-t$ axis (versus **time**) but its path is a line in the $x-y$ plane. So the length of the arc has no meaning here unless the particle's motion was in at least 2 directions.

Comment: Imagine a particle is just moving forward and backward in one direction... do you see any curves?!

Comment: Note: Don't misinterpret $x-y$ with $x-t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity $x(t) = 10t - 2t^2$ represents the position of the particle at time $t$.  To find the displacement from $t = 0$ to $t = 3$, we subtract $x(0)$ from $x(3)$.  However, the displacement is not equal to the distance if the particle changes direction (it does).  To determine the direction of the particle, look at the sign of the velocity, $x'(t)$.  Determine the time interval in which the particle is moving to the left and calculate its displacement during this interval.  Do the same for the time interval in which it is moving to the right.  To find the total distance traveled by the particle, add the absolute values of the displacements to the left and right.

Comment: @dxiv You are correct.  I should be in bed.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your idea of using an integral:

The total distance $D$ travelled is the area between the velocity-time graph and the time-axis where $v(t) = \frac{d x(t)}{d t}= 10-4t$:

$D = \int_0^3|v(t)|dt$

[image]